# Unable to get tkinter buttons to position correctly

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the buttons to be on opposite sides of the screen, but I'm unsure as to why they keep positioning themselves in the middle. The code is set up like this because I plan on having multiple overlays that I switch between with the `show_frame` method. The class `InputWindow` is one of those overlays. When I created a basic script with only window and buttons, I was able to get the buttons positioned properly, but I'm unsure as to what I'm doing incorrectly here that's preventing me from distancing the buttons properly.

```
import tkinter as tk

class GuiController(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args , **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  

        container = tk.Frame(self) 
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}
        frame = InputWindow(container, self)  
        self.frames[InputWindow] = frame
        frame.pack()
        self.show_frame(InputWindow)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class InputWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):   
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)  

        controller.geometry("650x500")

        button_defaultGame = tk.Button(self, text = "Default Game")
        button_defaultGame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "W")

        button_test = tk.Button(self, text = "Test")
        button_test.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "E")


        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=2)


app = GuiController()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `InputWindow` itself is shrinking to fit its contents - nothing you can do with the Buttons will make them move, since there's no extra room for them to move within.  When you `.pack()` (or `.grid()`) `InputWindow`, you need to tell it to expand to fill the root window.

Comment: Why you call `container.row_configure(...)` and `container.column_configure(...)`, but use `frame.pack()`? Should you use `frame.grid(sticky='nsew')` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When struggling with layout problems it helps to give your frames distinctive colors. Otherwise it can be difficult to see where one frame ends and another begins.

For example, give the container a color like this:

```
container = tk.Frame(self, bg="bisque")
```

Next, give your `InputWindow` a different color like this:

```
class InputWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="pink")
```

When you run the code you'll see something like this:

[image: screenshot]

This immediately makes it clear that `InputWindow` is not filling the container window. Looking through your code we can see that you're doing `frame.pack()` to add the instance of `InputWindow` to `container`.

Instead, you need to request that `InputWindow` fills the container window. You do that by changing  your call to `pack` to look like this:

```
frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Now we can see that the instance of `InputWindow` fills the container, and your buttons do indeed sit on the edges of the window.

[image: screenshot after changing the pack arguments]